# Number being cast to int when using varargs in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, reflection, variadic-functions

I'm trying to do some Reflection with Actionscript 3 and found a problem.

The function below receives data of variable type (int, Number, Boolean). It then pass the data and it's type to a method that will do something according to the type.

```
function aFuncWithVarAgs(... data):void
{
    for(var i:uint=0; i < data.length; i++)
    {
        var typeName:String = describeType(data[i]).@name;

        doSomethingAccordingToType(typeName, data[i]);
    }
}
```

The problem is when I do this:

```
var aNumber:Number = 11.0;
var anInt:int = 11;

aFuncWithVarArgs(aNumber, anInt);
```

So, the *describeType* says that both *aNumber* and *anInt* are of the type *int*. Like this:

```
<type name="int" base="Object" isDynamic="false" isFinal="true" isStatic="false">
    <extendsClass type="Object"/>
    <constructor>
       <parameter index="1" type="*" optional="true"/>
    </constructor>
</type>
```

**EDIT:** I'm trying to write bytes to a ByteArray according to the type. Here's the function that I mentioned above that I should have shown you:

```
function doSomethingAccordingToType(typeName:String, data:Object):void
{
    switch (typeName)
    {
        case "Number":
             bytes.writeDouble(data);
             break;
        case "int":
             bytes.writeInt(data); 
             break;
        ...
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** So, again, the problem is that when I have, say 9.0 or any round float number, I'll have an integer written instead of a double or float, than I'll have problem when reading the data wherever I receive it, because I expect that 9.0 is written as a double and not an int.

**EDIT:** There's a way to enforce the type when passing the parameters to the function declared with varargs or a better way to do this without using a lib?

Cheers!

Comment: Yep, it's strange. Noticed, that it will be still Number, if init it with 11.01 for example

Comment: Maybe some sort of optimization by the flash compiler?

Comment: Yeah, if it's a round number, even if it is a float (Number in AS) it will be cast to int.

Comment: Yeah @danii it could be.

Comment: ...but do you guys know some alternative for this problem, without using a fixed argument count?

Comment: it's also casted to int even when pushing it into any array

Comment: @salaniojr could you describe your objectives? May be we could offer something

Comment: @TimofeiDavydik, I have edited, please take a look!

Answer (score 0):

If you need only class name you can use `getQualifiedClassName` instead of `describeType`

```
var n:Number = 11.1;
var i:int = 11;
trace(getQualifiedClassName(n));
trace(getQualifiedClassName(i));
```

Comment: This works nice, but when you pass the variables to the function (with varargs) in my example you get my error.